# How to write a mysql query for this requirement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table like below.

[image]

I want to get the total number of books donated by donation_organization_group and distinct by donation_pledge.

I wrote the sql query like below.

> select count(DISTINCT donation_pledge), sum(DISTINCT donation_no_of_books)
>   from e25_donations  WHERE
>                   `donation_organization_group` ="4-H Club"

By this query i am getting the result as 6 | 1248, in this result 96, 72 is skipping, but i want to skip only the repeating pledge.I want to get the total of 72 + 120 + 96 + 96 + 960 +72.
Some one please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the `DISTINCT` values first, and then `COUNT` and `SUM` them:

```
select count(donation_pledge), 
       sum(donation_no_of_books), 
       count(distinct donation_organization_name)
from (select distinct donation_pledge, 
             donation_no_of_books, 
             donation_organization_name
      FROM e25_donations 
      WHERE donation_organization_group ="4-H Club") d
```

Comment: @Mujahidh I have modified my query to give you the count of the distinct clubs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below - using a subquery

```
select count(donation_pledge),sum(donation_no_of_books)
from
(
select DISTINCT donation_pledge, donation_no_of_books
from e25_donations 
WHERE donation_organization_group ="4-H Club"
)A
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i want to get the total number of clubs participated in the donation also.Can you please help me.Here 4 clubs participated

Answer (score 1):

You could try aggregating twice here:

```
SELECT
    donation_organization_group,
    SUM(nb) AS num_distinct_books
FROM
(
    SELECT donation_organization_group, donation_pledge, MAX(donation_no_of_books) AS nb
    FROM e25_donations
    WHERE donation_organization_group = '4-H Club'
    GROUP BY donation_organization_group, donation_pledge
) t;
```

Comment: thank you, i don't want to get the donation_organization_group.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try this

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(donation_pledge) FROM e25_donations 
     WHERE donation_organization_group ="4-H Club" GROUP BY donation_pledge) 
     as donationPledge, 
    (SELECT SUM(donation_no_of_books) FROM e25_donations
     WHERE donation_organization_group ="4-H Club" GROUP BY donation_no_of_books)
     as donationNoOfBooks
```